# Get the node that a block is placed on without a route parameter?

Tags: 10

Is there a way to devise from a block instance that was placed in Layout Builder how to load up and extract what node (or entity) it was placed into?

We are indexing pages into Solr and some inline components that load the node from the current route for data are failing because Search API is loading the entities to index and not crawling paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A block placed in Layout Builder can load the `entity` context:

```
$entity = $this->getContextValue('entity');
```

This works in the block build method. If you are altering an existing block you can use a LayoutBuilderEvents::SECTION_COMPONENT_BUILD_RENDER_ARRAY event:

```
public function onBuildRender(SectionComponentBuildRenderArrayEvent $event) {
  $build = $event->getBuild();
  $contexts = $event->getContexts();
  if (isset($contexts['entity'])) {
    if ($entity = $contexts['entity']->getContextValue()) {
      $build['content'][] = ['#markup' => $entity->label()];
    }
  }
  $event->setBuild($build);
}
```

Comment: I'll check - I think someone is trying to load this from hook_preprocess_block. If this does not work from there, is it possible to add a property via BlockComponentRenderArray event and then see it?

Comment: Yes, this looks good. This event has even a contexts property.